# Remove Whitespace from Line Item in ListBox (VB)

Tags: vb.net, listbox, whitespace

I'm trying to remove all spaces in on all Line Items in a ListBox. I would have assumed I could just throw in a normalize whitespace function but that doesn't appear to be the case. Long story short, I'm trying to write a program that counts the number of XML Fields from a file. I'd like to display all the fields but kill all the spacing in front of it (since it's formatted as XML).

```
'Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1
    Dim theFile As StreamReader
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLoadTheFile.Click

        'Load the File
        theFile = New StreamReader("C:\Users\Marc Wilson\Documents\XML\sampledata.xml")

        While (theFile.Peek > -1)

            ListBox1.Items.Add(theFile.ReadLine)

        End While
        theFile.Close()

        'Only get the fields
        Dim numberOfLines As Integer = ListBox1.Items.Count
        For i = 0 To numberOfLines - 1

            Dim theLineItem As String = ListBox1.Items.Item(i).ToString
            If theLineItem.Contains("<my:") And theLineItem.Contains("/>") Then
                ListBox2.Items.Add(theLineItem)
            End If
        Next   

        'Count items
        lblCount.Text = ListBox2.Items.Count.ToString

    End Sub   
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

this will remove leading and trailing spaces

```
theFile.ReadLine.trim
```

Comment: Consider [marking the post as a correct answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/208536) **if you think it was useful to you**. You have no obligation about it. Read the [help](http://stackoverflow.com/helpcenter/someone-answers) about accepting answers.